# Separate validation logic from UI flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to perform form validation on TextFields by creating a separate class away from the UI.

```
class ValidationRules {
  emailValidation() {
    if (email.isEmpty) {
     return 'Please enter your email address';
      
    }
    if (RegExp(
            r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
        .hasMatch(email)) {
       return null;
      
    }
     return 'This is not a valid email address;
  }

  passwordValidation() {
    if (password.isEmpty) {
       return 'Please enter your email address';
      
    }
  }
}
```

I am then accessing the functions by calling it on the validator property of the TextField widget

```
validator: _validationRules.emailValidation()
```

I receive the following error:

The following _TypeError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type '((String?) => String?)?'

Clearly, I cannot return the error messages as they are of String type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you please try this:
validator:(String? e)=> _validationRules.emailValidation()

Comment: @Adnan this is a great answer. It worked.